# Fork Adjustment

Tags: fork, suspension

When I ride into my new bike the fork doesn't shrink. My weight is about 81kgs. I think good forks usually shrink to 75% of its length. In my case it does not shrink at all.

The fork is cheap. Does not have any preload settings with it. Also is does not have lockout functionality.

Is there any way to make it softer? Maybe by opening it and do some hacking. Not sure though.

The fork manufacturer is Zoom. Here is the details.

[image: Fork details image]

My fork is same. Except its color is white.

Comment: What are the make and model of the fork?

Comment: Sounds like defective. And your warranty is void if you open it up. The basic property of suspension forks is to compress, you know. You could post a picture, however, just to be sure.

Comment: I have added with fork details

Comment: They say `lockout`, so it is most probably locked out now. Identify the lockout and preload adjust knobs and make sure the lockout is disengaged.

Comment: There are only two knobs (see the black nobs on top). None of them say "preload" or "lock". There is no arrow too. No indication of lock.

Comment: Can the knobs twist (with hand, not tools)? It could have just be not labeled. If you bought the bike from a bike shop, I would recommend that you pay them a visit. If it is from a department store, it will probably take a month to obtain their service, and I would be more courageous with opening up the fork and finding out what's wrong. It's probably less than $20 after all.

Comment: @Vorac yeah, I was getting adventurous just because of the low price. I just open those knobs. The is nothing inside. Just a hollow tube. may be the spring is down bellow.

Comment: [Here](http://srsuntour-files.dbap.de/_public/tuningbase/downloadarea/catalogs/SRSuntour_Workshop_Book.pdf) are some example schematics. This fork dissection is worth a separate question on it's own. Happy learning!

Answer (score 1):

Fork specs clearly say peload and lockout despite your claim that it has neither. However, looking at the image, I only see preload knobs. Not sure where the mechanical lockout lever is... So I have two guesses either A)it's locked out and the lockout knob is not very obvious, or B)The fork is inexpensive and stiff and therefore you are not experiencing any "sag" (The compression to ~75% when the fork is loaded with your weight). The perception of lack of sag is likely exaggerated by the fact that the fork only has 50mm of travel. As you get into mid priced forks, most start at 80-100mm of travel.